# Chain commands and ignore error

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to run the command `rm -rf lib && some command` which removes the `lib/` directory, then builds my project which gets outputted to `lib/`.

The `rm` will fail if `lib/` doesn't exist and won't execute the second command. How can I format this such that it will wait until the first command is done before starting the second and will continue to the second even if there is an error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a semi-colon (`;`) to separate the commands instead.

For more information see this Unix thread:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators